# Reduce the size of PDF in Node

Tags: node.js, pdf, compression, html-pdf

I am using html-pdf library of node to generate pdf on the client side , but the generated pdf size is extraordinarily huge , the same pdf content is being used to generate pdf using itext on the client side. The difference in the size of the pdf are in the range of mb. The client side pdf size is around 287kb abd the server side pdf account is of around 8mb. Is their any options or compression library to compress the pdf generated by html-pdf node module or any library I can append to reduce it.

Comment: @AlokParatapSingh Please provide what you've tired to do. Provide some code samples and community will surely help you out to get your desired results. Thanks :)